# Get the dimensions of the selected region

Tags: plugins, height, width, dimensions

I am working on redesigning my app. For this i am looking for an app that gives the dimensions of the selected area of the screen.

For Example. if i select a portion of the screen , it should return the dimensions of the selected area. something like (width*height). I see there is one plug-in for google chrome called dimensions, but it really does not work on images. I am looking for a tool which gives the dimensions even on images.

Can any one please suggest any tool for getting the dimensions of the selected area anywhere on the screen please?

Comment: Actually i just found one. Dont want to waste time of others here. I found a plugin in firefox called "MeasureIt" which gives the result. Please suggest if there is any better and convenient tool than MeasureIt.

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin for Firefox called "MeasureIt". Just in case it would be useful for someone.